# No ServletContext set trying to enable Spring MVC with a jetty webserver

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, jetty

I am trying to enable Spring-MVC in an existing application, having a jetty web server. I have two classes with `@Configuration`, one with all the beans from application and one where i enabled mvc using `@EnableWebMvc`. Than, before start jetty server, i set the handler adding `DispatcherServlet`. The problem is that after setting spring context i need to get a bean from it, but when i call refresh on context i receive:

```
 Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
```

I am trying to init context for getting bean in a non-spring class because is a legacy class:

```
private void initSpringAppContext() {
        this.springAppContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ((AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext) this.springAppContext).register(SpringConfiguration.class);
        ((AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext) this.springAppContext).refresh();
    }
```

SpringWebConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.whitelist.manager.resources")
public class SpringWebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {


}
```

SpringConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({"com.netoptics", "com.whitelist.manager", "com.websilicon", "com.wsnms.server", "com.anue", "com.wsnms"})
public class SpringConfiguration {

    @Bean
        .....
        @Bean
        .....

}
```

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
            <servlet-name>springMvc</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
                <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>com.netoptics.server.SpringWebConfiguration</param-value>
            </init-param>
        </servlet>


    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.netoptics.server.SpringConfiguration</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springMvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/v2/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

The problem is on this line: `springAppContext.refresh();`
If i remove this one, and i try to call `springAppContex.getBean()` i receive:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
```

UPDATE: Tried to change java configuration with XML, same error. When i try to get spring context (`SpringConfiguration.class`). So i am not able to get root context for accessing beans. What am i doing wrong in the `initSpringAppContext()`

Comment: Was something cut off? that last sentence seems incomplete.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt edit